# Conversion from base twelve to base ten and vice versa on an Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

What is the most efficient way of converting from base twelve to base ten and vice versa?

I have tried numerous ways of converting, such as converting to string, assign each char as value, multiply by `base^exponent` to get value in that base, and then get the total.

I was wondering, is there a better approach to this?

Firstly, I am storing the number as a string in base ten and want to convert it to base twelve as another string. I would also like to be able to convert that base twelve number (in a string) to a base ten number (in a string).

Comment: Do you need to print a numeric literal in base 12 or 10? Because converting a number, which is a value and not a representation, doesn't make any sense to me. You can't *convert* a number between two bases because its value will be stored always in the same way anyway.

Comment: Is the number of fingers on your hand base-10 or base-12? What about the number of hours in a day?

Comment: Numbers in a computer are always in binary. Do you want a text representation in that base instead?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I will edit the post. Firstly, I am storing the number as a string in base ten and want to convert it to base twelve as another string. I would also like to be able to convert that base twelve number (in a string) to a base ten number (in a string).

Comment: See this piece of code http://www.phanderson.com/C/baseprnt.html

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup This works perfect from base ten to whatever but not back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you just use base 2 as an intermediate.  You can convert from a string in any base to base 2 like this:

```
int x = strtol("12345", NULL, 10); // convert from base 10 string to integer
int y = strtol("12345", NULL, 12); // convert from base 12 string to integer
```

Then to convert *to* base 10 is trivial:

```
sprintf(buf, "%d", y); // convert from integer to base 10 string
```

To print out a number in base 12 is a bit tougher - there isn't a built-in function that already does it, so you need to write your own (with some helpers to keep things clean):

```
void reverse(char *s)                // reverse a string in place
{
    char *e = s + strlen(s) - 1;     // find the end of the string
    char tmp;
    while (s < e)                    // loop to swap characters and move pointers
    {                                // towards the middle of the string
        tmp = *e;
        *e-- = *s;
        *s++ = tmp;    
    }
}

char digit(int x)        // turn an integer into a single digit
{
    if (x < 10)
        return '0' + x;       // 0-9
    else
        return 'a' + x - 10;  // a, b, c, d, e, f, g....
}

void tobase(char *s, int x, int base) // convert an integer into a string in
{                                     // the given base
    int r;
    char *p = s;
    while (x)
    {
        r = x % base;    // extract current digit
        x = x / base;    // divide to get lined up for next digit
        *p++ = digit(r); // convert current digit to character
    }
    *p = '\0';           // null terminate the string
    reverse(s);          // and reverse it, since we generated the digits 
}                        // backwards
```

You'd use it like:

```
tobase(buf, x, 12); // convert from integer to base 12 string
```

You probably want to add better error handling than I have there - I was shooting for a short implementation for purposes of fitting it here cleanly.

Comment: This - `return 'a' + x;` should probably be `return 'a' + x - 10;`

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be exactly what I need. I'll add the error handling to it but so far it doesn't take as much flash memory as the way I did before (1KiB in fact!).

Comment: Good to hear.  I just noticed a small inefficiency in the reversing; there's no real reason to have to call `strlen`, since `tobase` already has both `s` and `p` pointers - you could pass `p - 1` and replace `e` with that in the `reverse` function.

Comment: Alternatively you can compute the base-12 log before you start, and write the digits backwards into their correct places. Computing the log shouldn't take any longer than the loop in `reverse` already takes, because if you can't find a faster way you can compute successive powers of 12 until you find one bigger than the input or reach `INT_MAX / 12`. Btw, `tobase` doesn't cope with negative numbers, but that's an easy fix if required.